# Batch file not working in server but working local

Tags: c#, asp.net, batch-file, iis, server

I created a batch file in my asp.net web site, It is working within the local system without any problem. After I was upload it to my web site's server (shared server), it is not working in the remote environment.

Here is a screenshot of the error I'm receiving  [image: Server Error in '/' Application]

This is the code I'm using to test run the batch on the server.

```
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/SourceCode/Jsil");
    Response.Write(path+"<br>");
    string batpath=Server.MapPath("~/Dir.bat");
    string framework = Server.MapPath("~/SourceCode/v4.0.30319");
    string vscompiler = @"\csc.exe /t:exe /r:JSIL.dll;JSIL.Meta.dll Program.cs";
    string full = framework + vscompiler;
    Response.Write(full);
    StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(batpath);
    file.WriteLine("G:");
    file.WriteLine("cd " + path);
    file.Write(full);
    file.Close();
    //Excecute bat file
    System.Diagnostics.Process compile = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    compile.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(batpath);
    compile.Start();
    compile.Close();
```

Comment: Is path on G:?  Instead of G: followed by "cd path", use "cd /d path".  Then you don't have to worry whether path is actually on G.

Comment: in local it is working fine with these code, in server it showing this error , path is working fine. i dnt no y these error comes in server please assist me to restify the error

Comment: our server location on g: thats y i giving that g over thr .. ..

Comment: Please don't write in text speak - not all of us understand it.  It says it is blocked by group policy.  Presumably it is running as localuser.  Check the server logs, see if you can find out which policy is blocking it and whether it can be disabled for localuser.

Comment: Find out which user account is running your application pool in the remote IIS, or if you've overwritten by using Impersonation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118%28v=vs.71%29.aspx. Once you have identified the user account that is running your worker process, then make sure that that worker process has rights to execute the BAT file. I would be surprised if the server would allow for something like that. If the server doesn't allow it (since that's what the exception is implying), then you have your answer right there.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that if it's a third-party shared server, then you'll have to contact them to find out how you can get rights to execute (though I doubt they will give it to you), and if it's your own shared server, then modify the group policy to allow for the execution of the BAT file. You have more permissions over your local system than some server out there.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a simple problem of privileges. The application user might not have execute privilege in the server box. You need to contact your system administrator and ask him to provide execute privilege to the IIS app pool user in the server.